# reading comprehension: redundant or implicit meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, redundancy

I am learning English from reading articles every day.  I have recently read "Writers in the Storm" by Kathryn Schulz (link: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/11/23/writers-in-the-storm), and I have a question.

There is a sentence...

> As in earlier, religious stories, meteorology here is morality, and
> the prevailing conditions leave everything hidden, murky, and stained.

I have no idea why the author added *", religious stories"* in the sentence.  Does it add any meaning?  It seems to be redundant to me.  However, I still believe there might be an implicit meaning to the reading, so I'd like to ask about the sentence.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it would be redundant. What else in the sentence means the same thing or fills the same role?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I was confused at first.  I didn't know "religious stories" would add meaning to "earlier".  I thought "earlier" was some kind of a time period, so I would always expect something like "earlier, during the rise of religious stories..."  In this case, there was a single word "religious stories", which is not a time period.  That made me confused.

Comment: However, it is much more clearer.  Thank you very much!  Also, thanks for Jack's answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not redundant. She is saying that in the novel Bleak House, "meteorology is morality", and that that is how it appeared in the "earlier, religious stories" that she has already discussed in the article.  Look again at the part starting with

> From the bag of winds gifted to Aeolus to the Biblical drought visited on Jerusalem, meteorological phenomena first appear in the narrative record as tools used by deities to battle one another and to help or hinder humans.

Those were "religious stories".

Comment: Very good explanation!  So that means she thinks "religious stories" also consider "meteorology is morality" like Bleak House?

Comment: Yes, I think so.